# Class/Method to check if table exists in SE11 or not?

Tags: abap, sap-data-dictionary

I want to check if a table exists in SE11 or not through ABAP.

Their are some FM's available like "C_TABLE_EXISTENCE"....
But i can't use FM's.
I want to use or have to use Class and its methods in my software.

Please suggest me, how can i check existence of a table without using any FM.
Preferably Class and Method.

Comment: Why do you "have to use" a method?

Comment: I have to use method because, my client does not give permission or they dont wont this particular FM's to be used for some reasons.

Comment: Sorry to say, but this is just plain stupid. I don't want to start a lengthy rant here, but how about telling them to type their e-mails without using a keyboard - just because? Stupid, I don't have any other word for it.

Comment: @vwegert Thanks for your advice, but you can't say like this.
Because, we have to listen to our customers in any how...
Please provide me a solution if you know
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the class cl_rebf_ddic_tabl

It's exists will return you X if the object (Table, Structure or View) exists i SE11

EG:

```
CALL METHOD cl_rebf_ddic_tabl=>exists
  EXPORTING
    id_name     = [table name]
    id_tabclass = 'TRANSP'  " For table
*    if_noview   = ABAP_FALSE
  receiving
    rf_exists   = yes
    .
```

Comment: Be aware that this class is part of the `RE-FX` package and thus not guaranteed to exist on every ABAP system.

Answer (score 3):

The official API to check whether a dictionary data type exists is the function module `DDIF_NAMETAB_GET`. It features a rather comprehensive documentation. Be aware that it will work for various kinds of tables and data structures and make sure you check the `DDOBJTYPE`.

If for whatever reason (maybe this is a homework assignment..?) you have to restrict yourself to method calls, you can use the RTTI classes (descendants of `CL_ABAP_TYPEDESCR`) - but be aware that this is a bit more work because you have to ensure that what you got is actually a table. The RTTI classes will return descriptors of any data type, even the internal ABAP runtime types, while `DDIF_NAMETAB_GET` is restricted to dictionary types.

Answer (score 0):

```
  CALL METHOD cl_abap_structdescr=>describe_by_name
    EXPORTING
      p_name = tabname
    EXCEPTIONS
      OTHERS = 1.
  IF sy-subrc <> 0.
    WRITE: `Table ` && tabname && ` does not exist`.
    RETURN.
  ENDIF.
```

---

To validate results manually, call SE11 (or SE16, table DD02L).

Answer (score -1):

You should take a look at the function module `DD_OBJECT_EXISTS` , it will be helpful.