# Class/Method/FM to check if a structure exists in se11 in abap

Tags: abap

I want to check if a structure is there in se11 or not.
There are classes to check for a class particularly and
also to check for tables. But is there a way I can check
whether a structure exists in se11 or not via code in ABAP?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Class/Method to check if table exists in SE11 or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20350734/class-method-to-check-if-table-exists-in-se11-or-not)

Answer (score 2):

The definition of a DDIC Structure is stored primarily in the tables `DD02L` (one line per structure) and `DD03L` (the components of the structures).

The structure name is in the column `TABNAME` of `DD02L`. This table contains also other types of objects; it's the column `TABCLASS` which distinguishes which type is each object. It has the value "**`INTTAB`**" for the structures.

You have several function modules to read these tables, one of them being `DDIF_TABL_GET`, but there are probably many more ones. I think that none is officially released.

There's also an official solution, which is to find if a type is a type in the dictionary, **but** it's not possible to distinguish if it's a structure, a table or a view. It's the class `CL_ABAP_TYPEDESCR` (RTTI). It has some ABAP Dictionary methods. The code is a little bit long to provide, so please confirm if that's a possible solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

Structures in Data Dictionary have a lot in common with DB tables. Therefore [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20350734/class-method-to-check-if-table-exists-in-se11-or-not) would answer your question too.

You can also use `CHECK_TAB_NAME` function module as suggested [here](https://answers.sap.com/questions/4222278/function-module-to-check-the-existance-of-a-table.html).